# Maximal ideal contained in an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

There is probably a simple answer to this but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Every ring in this question has a unit but isn't necessarily commutative.

Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be a left ideal of $R$. In *Basic Algebra II*, Jacobson defines
$$(I:R)=\{ b \in R \mid bR \subseteq I\}.$$
This is an ideal because it equals, $\text{ann}_R R/I$, the annihilator of the left $R$-module $R/I$. Because $R$ has a $1$ it follows that $(I:R)$ is contained in $I$. The author goes on to claim that $(I:R)$ contains every left ideal of $R$ properly contained in $I$, but I'm not seeing it.

If $J$ is a left ideal of $R$ contained in $I$ why should it be that $J \subseteq (I:R)$? The "obvious" thing would be to say that that since $J$ is an ideal $JR \subseteq J \subseteq I$, but the rings here aren't necessarily commutative and $J$ is only a left ideal so this doesn't work. Is there any sort of reason this actually works given that $J$ is properly contained in $I$?

Comment: I think you answered your question, for every j in J, jR contained in JR that is equal to J which is contained in I and so j is an element of (I:R) by definition.

Comment: Yeah, thats about the simple type of answer I was expecting. Thanks.

Comment: @yanko $J$ is a left ideal, so generally $JR\ne J$.

Comment: I always confuses right and left, thanks for the correction and great answer

Comment: ahh, or not such a simple answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic Algebra II, edition of 1980, page 188:

> Let $I$ be a left ideal of the ring $R$. We define
>   $$
> (I:R)=\{b\in R\mid bR\subset I\}.\tag{9}
> $$
>   It is clear that if we put $M=R/I$ and we regard this as a left $R$-module then
>   $$
> (I:R)=\operatorname{ann}_RR/I.\tag{10}
> $$
>   It follows from this or $(9)$ that $(I:R)$ is an ideal. Moreover, by $(9)$, $(I:R)\subset I$ and $(I:R)$ contains every ideal of $R$ contained in $I$. In other words, $(I:R)$ is the (unique) largest ideal contained in $I$.

I don't think this has changed in later editions, because it is generally false that $(I:R)$ contains every left ideal of $R$ (properly) contained in $I$. Consider the ring $R$ of $3\times 3$ matrices over the field $F$. Then $R=I_1\oplus I_2\oplus I_3$ as a direct sum of minimal left ideals. Take $I=I_1\oplus I_2$: then $(I:R)=0$, but $I$ properly contains the left ideal $I_1$.

Note that *ideal* (without the adjective left or right) means “two-sided ideal” and that $\subset$ denotes inclusion (not necessarily proper).

Comment: It looks like that does it, but isn't it still a counterexample to his claim? If $(I:R)$ contains every left ideal of $R$ contained in $I$ then it in particular contains every left ideal of $R$ properly contained in $I$. If the ring is commutative then it looks like $(I:R)=I$ so I should drop the proper containment anyway.

Comment: @RobinAllison It is *false* that $(I:R)$ contains all left ideals properly contained in $I$. If the ring is commutative, then of course the largest ideal contained in $I$ is $I$, so $I=(I:R)$ (which is also obvious directly). There is no mention of “proper containment” in the text. Jacobson used $\subset$ to denote inclusion, proper or not.